# Socat: send a UDP broadcast from stdin, but handling responses with SYSTEM

Tags: networking, udp, socat

I'm trying to implement a simple proprietary discovery protocol using `socat`. The discovery is done by sending a UDP broadcast to a well-defined port with a small payload, then listening to "replies" from these devices on my network.

This works if I use bidirectional `socat` and "responses" go to stdout:

```
echo -ne "\x00\x01\x00\xF6" | socat -t5 - udp-datagram:255.255.255.255:30718,broadcast |xxd -p
```

Example responses from a few devices on my local network (each line is a response from a different device):

```
000000f70020300258366d112c15000062a71b21ff0000000080a3d2ded9
000000f70020300258366d112c15000062a71b21ff0000000080a3a40670
000000f70020300258366d112c15000062a71b21ff0000000080a3b94ca0
000000f70020300258366d112c15000062a71b21ff0000000080a3a4046b
```

The payloads are what I expect, *however* what I'm missing is the sender metadata, specifically the sender's IP that I would get if I used `ip-pktinfo,fork SYSTEM:`. So what I want is to send the initial broadcast from stdin but use `SYSTEM` to handle the resulting packets coming back.

I've tried a few variations of `-u` unidirectional mode but I don't seem to receive data on my listener:

```
# Listener: 
socat -u udp-recvfrom:30222,reuseaddr,ip-pktinfo,fork SYSTEM:./test.sh &

# Broadcast:
echo -ne "\x00\x01\x00\xF6" | socat -u - udp-datagram:255.255.255.255:30222,sourceport=30222,broadcast,reuseaddr
```

Note from "this end" the source port may be random so I'm explicitly choosing `30222` so my broadcast source port will match my response listener.  e.g. if the broadcast comes from port 9987 clients will send their unicast response back to port 9987.  If I run the unidirectional broadcast this way, I will *occasionally* get a response; I have a feeling it depends on how quickly the broadcast process quits.

(I intend to check packet captures next; I'm testing on a remote machine and I have to refresh my memory on `tcpdump` first.)

References:

- http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html
- http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#ADDRESS_UDP_DATAGRAM

Comment: @A.B sorry I never saw the notification of your response!  You're right - I was missin the `reuseport` option; I think I expected `reuseaddr` to have the same effect which obv it did not.  Thanks so much for your thorough explanation!

Comment: (deleted wrong comment doh): SO_REUSEADDR helps when using TCP sockets in listening mode to avoid getting "Address already in use" when binding again to the same address/port after having closed it before (when a client was connected): that's to bypass the TIME_WAIT state delay. No effect on UDP afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP mentions `ip-pktinfo` which is usually a Linux socket option (for `IP_PKTINFO`). I'll assume Linux below (but see notes at the end for *BSD). This option is actually not needed (also see notes at the end), but could be added for additional information.

---

The key part is to use the option `reuseport` which toggles the [`SO_REUSEPORT`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/socket.7#Socket_options) socket option:

> `SO_REUSEPORT` (since Linux 3.9)
>
> Permits multiple AF_INET or AF_INET6 sockets to be bound to an identical socket address. This option must be set on each socket
> (including the first socket) prior to calling bind(2) on the socket.
> To prevent port hijacking, all of the processes binding to the same
> address must have the same effective UID. This option can be employed
> with both TCP and UDP sockets.

Except for this missing option, OP already got all that was needed.

Mostly for other readers' benefit, I'll describe what's done and give a complete example.

---

If one *socat* command can't do the work due to limitations, using two *socat*, splitting the full-duplex communication channel into two simplex channels, will for this case.

One will be used for reading back the answers, the other for sending the broadcast. Again, to workaround *socat* limitations, the reading *socat* has to use `UDP-RECVFROM` with `fork` and `-u` (for read-only, so its results are going to *stdout*, rather than being sent back to the responder) rather than the normally natural choice of `UDP-RECV`: that's to allow to fork one command per packet and transmit via environment variables the metadata for each packet. Also as OP wrote, a port has to be chosen in advance in order to have them both use the same. The sending socket too must use `-u` to avoid risking to read back the answer and stealing it to the other dedicated *socat* command.

Here's an example in a LAN with the local system having 192.0.2.2/24 and the peer system having 192.0.2.3/24.

peer system (responder) named *peer*:

```
$ socat udp4-recvfrom:30718,fork system:hostname
```

local system's term1 (could optionally also use `,ip-pktinfo`):

```
$ socat -u udp4-recvfrom:30222,reuseport,fork system:'cat; printenv|grep -E \"SOCAT_.*(ADDR|PORT)\"'
```

local system's term2:

```
$ echo dummyprobe | socat -u - udp-datagram:255.255.255.255:30718,bind=:30222,reuseport,broadcast
```

response received on term1:

```
peer
SOCAT_PEERADDR=192.0.2.3
SOCAT_PEERPORT=30718
```

---

Notes

- FreeBSD has a description similar for [`SO_REUSEPORT`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsockopt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) (or rather, [Linux aligned lately to *BSD](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/)):

  > `SO_REUSEPORT` allows completely duplicate bindings by multiple
  > processes if they all set SO_REUSEPORT before binding the port. This
  > option permits multiple instances of a program to each receive
  > UDP/IP multicast or broadcast datagrams destined for the bound port.
- `ip-pktinfo` is not needed to retrieve *peer*'s address. It's needed to retrieve the *local* address and is mostly useful for a multi-homed system so it knows on which of its multiple addresses received a datagram, or else also to know if the received datagram was a broadcast. The peer's address information is always available even without this option. *BSD just requires to replace this option with `ip-recvdstaddr,ip-recvif` (=> `IP_RECVDSTADDR` + `IP_RECVIF`) to receive the same information.